# How to create Winforms Installer application with CMake

Tags: c#, winforms, cmake

I was wondering how to create a .msi installer or equivalent for a C# Winforms application with CMake? I have searched and found CPack but nothing mentions if it is capable of installing a Winforms application. I have dlls that need to be included with my .exe as well.

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic, but why *must* you use CMake? Depending on what version of Visual Studio you are using you could use deployment projects, ClickOnce, WIX, Advanced Installer. Windows Store could be an option, it depends on your application and how you want to distribute it; none of which you have told us.

Comment: The reason for CMake is because all of my dlls, and my executable projects are setup using CMake. I am using VS2015

Comment: CPack has a NSIS backend, you can use it to build a MSI.

Comment: @joe_chip Do you have an example? Basically I want CPack to take the .exe built by my C# target and take the .dll it needs and put it into a installer.

Comment: Did you see this? https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cpack/Component-Install-With-CPack

Comment: I haven't used it in a while, as far as I remember the documentation is quite lacking, unfortunately.

Comment: I just installed WIX and used that and it works fine. Thanks for contriubting!

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing C# project that is configured with CMake, the logical route would be to use [CPack](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html) to create a Winforms installer. CPack can target one of several generators (NSIS, WiX, etc.), but here's a simple example (with a library and an executable) using WiX.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.13)

# Create a C# project.
project(MyProj LANGUAGES CSharp)

# Include CMake utilities for CSharp, for WinForm and WPF application support.
include(CSharpUtilities)

# Group our library and executable source files.
set(DLL_SRCS
    MyDLL/MyClass.cs
    MyDLL/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
)
set(EXE_SRCS
    App.config
    Form1.cs
    Form1.Designer.cs
    Form1.resx
    Program.cs
    Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
    Properties/Resources.Designer.cs
    Properties/Resources.resx
    Properties/Settings.Designer.cs
    Properties/Settings.settings
)

# Create the DLL library.
add_library(MyLibrary SHARED ${DLL_SRCS})
# Create the Winforms executable.
add_executable(MyWinFormApp ${EXE_SRCS})

# Set the .NET Framework version.
set_property(TARGET MyLibrary PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION "v4.6.1")
set_property(TARGET MyWinFormApp PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION "v4.6.1")
# Set the executable to be 32-bit.
set_property(TARGET MyWinFormApp PROPERTY WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE)
# Set the C# language version (defaults to 3.0).
set(CMAKE_CSharp_FLAGS "/langversion:latest")

# Set the source file properties for Windows Forms use.
csharp_set_windows_forms_properties(
    ${DLL_SRCS}
    ${EXE_SRCS}
)

# If necessary, link in other library dependencies that were built locally in this source tree.
target_link_libraries(MyWinFormApp MyLibrary)

# Add in the .NET reference libraries.
set_property(TARGET MyLibrary PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES
    "Microsoft.CSharp"
    "System"
    "System.Core"
    "System.Data"
    "System.Drawing"
    "System.Windows.Forms"
)
set_property(TARGET MyWinFormApp PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES
    "Microsoft.CSharp"
    "System"
    "System.Core"
    "System.Data"
    "System.Drawing"
    "System.Windows.Forms"
)

# Set the installation configuration, putting the targets in the 'bin' folder.
install(TARGETS MyLibrary
    CONFIGURATIONS Release
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
)
install(TARGETS MyWinFormApp
    CONFIGURATIONS Release
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
)

# Tell CPack to use the WIX generator.
set(CPACK_GENERATOR WIX)
include(CPack)
# Set the CPACK and WIX variables here.
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "MyWinFormApp")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0.0")
set(CPACK_WIX_PROGRAM_MENU_FOLDER "My Winform Application")
```

When CMake generates the Visual Studio solution, a CMake Pre-defined project will appear in the Solution Explorer called **PACKAGE**; build this to create the installer.

The CPack WiX [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/wix.html#cpack-wix-generator) provides many, many variables allowing you to customize your installer with installation location, installer name, GUIDs, installer icons and branding logos, licenses, Start Menu and Desktop shortcuts, and more. I highly advise checking out CPack and CPack-WiX links to see which customization options are appropriate for your project.

Note, for my installation of WiX, I had to be sure .NET 3.5.1 was installed and [enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows-10#ControlPanel) on my machine as well.